# Easier way to move my text to make sure it is center with the box?

Tags: html, new-operator, code-cleanup

I am trying to make a website based off what I learned in High School and google.

I wanted to move some borders to the right and left of the page (which I can do) but the text inside it isn't (or looks) centered with the border outline. I fixed it by making a `div` with id for the text or links and moving them to the middle of the box, but then something in the back of my mind told me: "if someone isn't using google chrome it might not be centered or in a random place also if we need to move it we have to do this all over".

So my question is: What is a easier way to move my text to make sure it is center with the box?
 When I just moved it or added padding it made the text in the a link push together and look ugly.

Here is my code:

```css
html {
  background-color: #070738;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
li,
ul,
ol {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
  /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  /* Footer height */
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 43%;
  right: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#list {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  left: 44%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrap">
  <h1>Aries Tarot</h1>
  <div class="border">
    <div id="list">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="whoami.html">Who Am I</a></li>
        <br><br>
        <li><a href="witarot.html">What Is Tarot</a></li>
        <br><br>
        <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If anyone could help me clean this up Id be so greatfull

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
body {
  background-color: #070738;
}

#content-wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```
<div id="content-wrap">
  <h1>Aries Tarot</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="whoami.html">Who Am I</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="witarot.html">What Is Tarot</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so I tried it the way it's suppose to look and it ended up with the same problem I had  it. I took out the H1 tag and put it to a square shape and it still is to far from the left. I also moved it to the right and left of the screen using top right and left in the CSS and it does the same thing

Comment: sry I forgot the code  `body {
  background-color: #070738;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#content-wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid green;
    left: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;

}`